# Restart Python 3.6 GUI - wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, restart

So I built a GUI in python using wxpython, and I want to be able to restart it when I click on a button. I want the app to close, then open up again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by "restart". Do you want everything to be reinitialized? If not, you can just call `Hide` on the main window of your application. Put in an artificial sleep and then `Show` it again.

Alternatively, you would need to basically launch a script on shutdown that would then relaunch your application.